# Need to update cron expressed timer on runtime in camel quartz

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I need to update camel quartz cron based timer dynamically on runtime.

The timer cron expression is mentioned in DB and accordingly my scheduler is working and suppose it is 10 minutes interval.
Now if I update timer cron expression in DB(updated to 20 minutes interval), I am trying to update the cron expression in camel side which should run 20 minutes interval instead of 10 mins interval but not reflecting.

I have gone through couple of links but could not get much help:

[Camel runtime timer change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309081/camel-runtime-timer-change)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7153

Any guidance or example will be great to understand. Advance thanks.

If Camel does not provide such solution, which library will be best suitable for such use case. I have few in minds like (Java Timer, Spring Scheduler, Quartz Scheduler) and I feel these provides such provision.

Comment: Are you fetching the cron expession from the db using camel as well? it would help if you added your camel route here.

Comment: Now I am using Spring Quartz Scheduler instead of camel quartz which gives me dynamic start and stop provision with different schedulers and cron-experssions have been kept in environment properties file.